# stopping text overrun on input box HTML

Tags: html, css

I have got a input box for a email with the send button at the end of the input. I am trying to find a way to stop the text from over running on longer input's into under the send button and stop before it goes under

my code for this part is:

```
<form class="form" >
        <input type="email" class="form__field" placeholder="Your E-Mail Address" style="border-radius: 20px;"/>
        <button type="button" class="btn s btn--inside uppercase" style="top: 8px; color: black;">Send</button>
    </form>
```

[-Picture of input box-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaLGI.png)

[-Picture of problem-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHbKh.png)

any help on this would be helpful thank you

https://jsfiddle.net/rgL6e45f/

my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to introduce padding behind the button, essentially, or put them in different containers. Assuming your style has the button stuck to the right-hand edge of the box, you can do:

```css
.form__field {
  width: 275px; /* your width, minus the extra padding you give */
  padding-right: 96px; /* enough to offset px it hangs over input */
}
```

Comment: this buts a background on it but still don't stop the text from going behind it

Comment: Right, changed it once I realized.

Comment: thats my problem

Comment: Okay, that's much more helpful. Updating answer.

Comment: Excellent! You can mark it as the correct answer by clicking the checkmark above.

Comment: Updated to use CSS instead of JS/line comments. If you put `// comment...` in your CSS, be sure to take it out.

Answer (score 0):

set max-length

```
<input type="email" maxlength="50" class="form__field" placeholder="Your E-Mail Address" style="border-radius: 20px;"/>
```

Comment: max length don't fix as the text still goes under the button as the overlay of the button needs sorting

Answer (score 0):

Use padding-right and set it to a high enough value. Be aware that with i18n submit button values you need to look for a different solution (e.g. the styling on a parent element with the the input field and the submit button next to each other, where the input field takes the remaining space).